# Why does mounting only show the base image?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, mount, hyper-v

I have mounted my `vhdx` file as shown here:

```
Mount-WindowsImage -ImagePath “C:\VMs\VHDs\TestImage.vhdx” -Path C:\VHDMount -Index 1
```

The `TestImage.vhdx` has a number of differencing disks as well (a number of files in the same directory with the extension `ahdx`).

When I run `Mount-WindowsImage` it only shows my base image contents and not the final image content (from the last check point). Why?

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise for my host for Hyper-v and for the image I am trying to mount (so that I can create a wim).

Answer (score 0):

Mounting a VHD file this way does not allow you to also get the differencing disks, it only mounts the first VHD as specified in the cmdlet. The -index parameter should always be `1` when mounting VHDs.

The -index parameter is only useful for mounting WIM images because these files can have multiple images inside the same file.